# Inviting an optimal subset of persons such that all friends of a person invited are invited

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

Let's say that you want to invite a person $u$ in party $P$. The
person $u$ will join the party if and only if all the friends of $u$ will join the party as well. Otherwise, $u$ will reject your invitation. Hence, we have two sets: $P$ with all the persons, and $F$ with the friend relations. Suppose $(u, v)$ belongs to $F$. This means that $u$ treats $v$
as a friend of $u$, and thus $u$ will reject your invitation if $v$ does not join the party. Note that $(u, v) \in F$ doesn’t mean that $v$ treats $u$ as a friend of $v$. Also, every person $u$ in $P$ has a quality measure, $p_u$ (this can be positive or negative and is given). Now I need to find a subset of $P$, such that all those in the subset won't reject my invitation and the qualities among the people is maximized.

Here is an example of a feasible and non-feasible subset:
$P = \{a, b, c, d\}, F = \{(a, b),(a, c),(b, d),(b, c)\}, p_a = 10, p_b =
1, p_c = 1, p_d = −20$.
A subset $\{a, b, c\}$ is not feasible because $d$ is not
invited and thus $b$ rejects your invitation.
A subset $\{b, c, d\}$ is feasible with total quality is $p_b + p_c + p_d = −18$ which is not maximized. The optimal
subset $A$ of this example is $\{c\}$ with total quality is $p_c = 1$.

Now I need to design an algorithm that finds this optimal subset in $O(|P|(|P| + |F|)^2)$ time. 
My thoughts: 
The elements in $F$ are directed edges, and the elements in $P$ are the nodes. As we are kind of dealing with a maximum flow problem, and as the required running time resembles the running time of the Ford Fulkerson algorithm $O(VE^2)$, I thought, that $(|P| + |F|)$ should be the amount of edges in the graph. Hence, my thought was to split each node $u$ into two nodes, say $u(\mathrm{in})$ and $u(\mathrm{out})$ with the directed arc $u(\mathrm{in})\rightarrow u(\mathrm{out})$ and edge weight the $p_u$. This way we have $(|P| + |F|)$ edges. However, the max flow algorithm doesn't necessarily saturate the edges it travels. However, in my case, whenever a node is reached (person is invited)/edge is travelled it adds the full flow $p_u$.

How would you approach this problem? And what are your thoughts on how the algorithm should work?

Comment: Hello coursemate from comp3711 :)
A similar but more well-known problem is called "project selection" in max flow.

Comment: @MaaLee Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [closure problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_problem). I quote the Wikipedia paragraph describing the reduction to the max flow problem here.

> As Picard (1976) [1] showed, a maximum-weight closure may be obtained from $G$ by solving a maximum flow problem on a graph $H$ constructed from $G$ by adding to it two additional vertices $s$ and $t$. For each vertex $v$ with positive weight in $G$, the augmented graph $H$ contains an edge from $s$ to $v$ with capacity equal to the weight of $v$, and for each vertex $v$ with negative weight in $G$, the augmented graph $H$ contains an edge from $v$ to $t$ whose capacity is the negation of the weight of $v$. All of the edges in $G$ are given infinite capacity in $H$.
>
> A minimum cut separating $s$ from $t$ in this graph cannot have any edges of $G$ passing in the forward direction across the cut: a cut with such an edge would have infinite capacity and would not be minimum. Therefore, the set of vertices on the same side of the cut as $s$ automatically forms a closure $C$. The capacity of the cut equals the weight of all positive-weight vertices minus the weight of the vertices in $C$, which is minimized when the weight of $C$ is maximized. By the max-flow min-cut theorem, a minimum cut, and the optimal closure derived from it, can be found by solving a maximum flow problem.

---

[1]  Picard, Jean-Claude (1976), "Maximal closure of a graph and applications to combinatorial problems", *Management Science*, **22** (11): 1268–1272, doi:[10.1287/mnsc.22.11.1268](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.22.11.1268), MR [0403596](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0403596).